# IIS7 site working with example.com but not with www.example.com. DNS issue?

Tags: domain-name-system, hosting, asp.net, deployment

I have my domain name registered with GoDaddy and pointing to my IIS server where I have an ASP.net MVC application deployed.  To accomplish this I simply have an A record entry pointing to the IP Address of my IIS server.

The binding name of my IIS web application is `example.com`.  I can hit this just fine in the browser.  However, when I try to hit `www.example.com` it hits the default IIS website.  How do I get both `example.com` and `www.example.com` to hit my web application?  Do I need a special A record or CNAME entry?

I would also like `*.example.com` to hit my application.  Is there a way to do this in DNS or IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you get the default IIS page when you hit `www.example.com` means that your DNS is set up correctly. If the web site isn't the default web site (and it sounds like it isn't) then you need to add a host header to the web site for each "name" by which you want to access it. If you want to access it by `www.example.com`, then add that as a host header to the web site.

Comment: can you assign multiple host names in IIS7 within the Edit Site Bindings Screen?

Comment: Yes you can add as many host headers as you need.